# How to get another dataframe value according to the value of the column and set to the corresponding field

Tags: python, pandas

This is my two dataframe ,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['@1','A',2],['@2','A',1],['@3','A',4],['@4','B',1],['@5','B',1],['@6','B',3],['@7','B',3],['@8','C',4]],columns=['key1','key2','value'])

  key1 key2  value
0   @1    A      2
1   @2    A      1
2   @3    A      4
3   @4    B      1
4   @5    B      1
5   @6    B      3
6   @7    B      3
7   @8    C      4

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['@5','B',None],['@7','B',None],['@6','B',None],['@3','A',None],['@6','B',None]],columns=['key1','key2','value'])

  key1 key2 value
0   @5    B  None
1   @7    B  None
2   @6    B  None
3   @3    A  None
4   @6    B  None
```

I know I can use `isin` to select the df1's rows where key1+key2 is in the df2

```
df1[(df1['key1']+df1['key2']).isin(df2['key1']+df2['key2'])]

  key1 key2  value
2   @3    A      4
4   @5    B      1
5   @6    B      3
6   @7    B      3
```

but how can I assign df1's ['value'] to df2 , so that let df2 is

```
  key1 key2 value
0   @5    B  1
1   @7    B  3
2   @6    B  3
3   @3    A  4
4   @6    B  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.merge`

```
df2[['key1', 'key2']].merge(df1, 'left')

  key1 key2  value
0   @5    B      1
1   @7    B      3
2   @6    B      3
3   @3    A      4
4   @6    B      3
```

---

Or with `pd.DataFrame.join`

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2']
df2[keys].join(df1.set_index(keys).value, on=keys)

  key1 key2  value
0   @5    B      1
1   @7    B      3
2   @6    B      3
3   @3    A      4
4   @6    B      3
```

---

Supposing you want to update `df2` while leaving other columns intact.  You can `update` in place

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2']
df2.update(df2[keys].join(df1.set_index(keys).value, on=keys).value)
```

Or create a copy

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2']
df2.assign(value=df2[keys].join(df1.set_index(keys).value, on=keys).value)
```

Comment: thanks your answer , in this example it's work , but if I have another columns like ['abc'] , using join or merge will let 'abc' disappear , and I just want to reserve df2's columns ,any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can using `fillna`

```
df2.set_index(['key1','key2']).value.fillna(df1.set_index(['key1','key2']).value).\
        reset_index()
Out[84]: 
  key1 key2  value
0   @5    B      1
1   @7    B      3
2   @6    B      3
3   @3    A      4
4   @6    B      3
```

Comment: @RelaxZeroC Yw~ if you like Pir and my answer you can upvote them :-)